# Pyspark outputs the result incorrectly when using cast

Tags: pyspark

When using spark.sql, when the cast( ) function was called as decimal(38,16), however, as a result, it calculated not up to 16 decimal places, but up to 10 characters and filled the rest with zeros

The code of the unit is presented below:

```
        cast(
            AVG(
                CASE WHEN 
                    a.is_debtor = 1 AND 
                    a.is_kk = 0 AND 
                    a.is_open = 0 
                THEN datediff((a.date_end_plan + interval '1 day'), a.date_start)/(365.25/ 12) 
                END
            ) as decimal(38,16)
        )
 AS avg_term_plan_closed
```

As a result , the following result is output:

```
+--------------------+
|avg_term_plan_closed|
+--------------------+
| -3.2744695414000000|
| 11.2689938398000000|
|  0.9856262834000000|
|                null|
| -1.1498973306000000|
                  ...
+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

However, the result should look like this:

```
+--------------------+
|avg_term_plan_closed|
+--------------------+
| -3.2744695414099936|
| 11.2689938398357280|
|  0.9856262833675564|
|                null|
| -1.1498973305954825|
                  ...
+--------------------+
```

I tried to put CAST in any possible place in the code, but to no avail. Interestingly, if you remove the division by (365.25/ 12), the result will be correct.Please help me, I have been struggling with this error for a week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cast the divisor to float to get the desired output.

```py
spark.sql('select numdays, cast((numdays/cast(365.25/12 as float)) as decimal(38,16)) as c1 from samp').show()

# +-------+-------------------+
# |numdays|                 c1|
# +-------+-------------------+
# |    343|11.2689938398357280|
# +-------+-------------------+
```

without casting the divisor

```py
spark.sql('select numdays, cast(numdays/(365.25/12) as decimal(38,16)) as c1 from samp').show()

# +-------+-------------------+
# |numdays|                 c1|
# +-------+-------------------+
# |    343|11.2689938398000000|
# +-------+-------------------+
```